# Time out exception not thrown

Tags: android, http, exception, timeoutexception

Can some one please help me why this code does not throw time out exception.

```
httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    int some_reasonable_timeout = (int) (10 * DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, some_reasonable_timeout);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, some_reasonable_timeout);

    try {
    response = client.execute(request);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {   //catching timeout exception
        response = null;
    }
    return response;
```

I disconnect my computer from internet and then make a request from `android device`. but it does not throw `time out exception`. May be i am not getting when timeout exception throws. I want to do , when system does not respond in 10 sec quit the `request`. Please help me solving this issue.

---

updated

try this too

```
    //      httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
//      int some_reasonable_timeout = (int) (10 * DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
//      HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, some_reasonable_timeout);
//      HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, some_reasonable_timeout);
//      request.setParams(httpParams);

    setTimeouts(request.getParams());

    try {
    response = client.execute(request);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {   //catching timeout exception
        response = null;
        return response;
    }
    return response;
```

Comment: down voter please specify reason why you down vote it. whats wrong in it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout()` is [not working well](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2409). I'm not sure this will fit what you want to achieve, but works to me:

```
private static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 5000; // Timeout until a connection is established
private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 5000; // Timeout for waiting for data
private static final long MCC_TIMEOUT = 5000;

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
setTimeouts(httpGet.getParams());

private static void setTimeouts(HttpParams params) {
  params.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
  params.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
  params.setLongParameter(ConnManagerPNames.TIMEOUT, MCC_TIMEOUT);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *unable*? Have you tried and still happens the same?

Comment: it does not work. device is still continue to make a request.

Comment: It works to me, probably not a precise 5 second timeout but approximate. Are you sure you're calling the `setTimeouts()` method?

Comment: I guess you added also the `setTimeouts(...)` implementation in your code although you didn't include it in your question, right?